I am trying to write my own mysql client.but I send data to server always receive: "packets out of or ..."
I am trying to write my own mysql client.but I send data to server always receive:  "packets out of or ..."
I have been resolve server info and are successfully.
env:
mysql 8.0.32
Protocol::HandshakeV10
this is my code:
unsigned char stage0[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
unsigned char stage1[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
unsigned char stage2[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
unsigned char stage3[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
unsigned char stageAll[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

if (strcmp(MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.AuthPluginName.c_str(), MySQLPluginName.cachingSha2Password) == 0) {
// using caching_sha2_password
// XOR(SHA256(password), SHA256(SHA256(SHA256(password)), Nonce))
// globalVar.MySQL_Password is string, is mysql password.
        // first sha256 -> SHA256(password) general sha256 digest.
        SHA256((const unsigned char*) globalVar.MySQL_Password.c_str(), strlen(globalVar.MySQL_Password.c_str()), stage0);

        // second sha256 inner -> SHA256(password)
        SHA256((const unsigned char*) globalVar.MySQL_Password.c_str(), strlen(globalVar.MySQL_Password.c_str()), stage1);
        // SHA256(SHA256(password))
        SHA256((const unsigned char*) stage1, sizeof(stage1)/sizeof(stage1[0]), stage2);
        // stage2 + nonce
        // MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.ServerAuthDataPart: client recived 
exchange number.contain tow part.length: 8(one of part) + 12(two of part).
        for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
            MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.ServerAuthDataPart += stage2[i];
        }
        // SHA256(SHA256(SHA256(password)), Nonce)
        SHA256((const unsigned char*)MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.ServerAuthDataPart.c_str(), strlen(MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.ServerAuthDataPart.c_str()), stage3);
        // stage0 ^ stage3 -> XOR(SHA256(password), SHA256(SHA256(SHA256(password)), Nonce)) 
        for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
            stageAll[i] = stage0[i] ^ stage3[i];
        }
    } else if (strcmp(MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.AuthPluginName.c_str(), MySQLPluginName.mysqlNativePassword) == 0) {
        // sha1
        ...
    } else {
        printf("unknown auth plugin: %s", MySQLServInfo.MySQLServInfoData.AuthPluginName.c_str());
        return 0;
    }
    // CapabilityFlags1
    
    // length of stage3
    const int authRespLen = sizeof(stage3);
    uint8_t authRespLEIBuf[9];
    // return authRespLEI = 32. SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH's length
    uint8_t* authRespLEI = appendLengthEncodedInteger(authRespLEIBuf, authRespLen);

    // send data length
    const int pktLen = 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 23 + strlen(MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.UserName.c_str()) + 1 + 33 +
                       strlen(MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.DataBaseName.c_str()) + 1 + strlen(MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.ClientPluginName.c_str()) + 1;
    uint8_t data[pktLen];
    // From mysql source code: CLIENT_BASIC_FLAGS, define:
    // #define CLIENT_BASIC_FLAGS                                          \
    // (CLIENT_ALL_FLAGS &                                               \
    // ~(CLIENT_SSL | CLIENT_COMPRESS | CLIENT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT | \
    // CLIENT_ZSTD_COMPRESSION_ALGORITHM))
    MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.CapabilityFlagsAll = CLIENT_BASIC_FLAGS;

    int position = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        data[position] = (pktLen-4 >> (i * 8)) & 0b11111111;
        position += 1;
    }
    data[position] = 1;
    position += 1; // 4
    data[position] = MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.CapabilityFlagsAll;
    position += 1;
    data[position] = 0x00;
    position += 1;
    data[position] = 0x00;
    position += 1;
    data[position] = 0x00;
    position += 1;
    // max packet length
    data[position] = pktLen;
    position += 1;
    data[position] = 0x00;
    position += 1;
    data[position] = 0x00;
    position += 1;
    data[position] = 0x00;
    position += 1;
    // character set
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; ++i) {
        data[position] = MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.Filler[i];
        position += 1;
    }
    // username 
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.UserName.c_str()) + 1; i++) {
        data[position] = MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.UserName[i];
        position += 1;
    }

    data[position] = authRespLEI; // stageAll length 32
    position += 1;
    // append to data
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
        data[position] = stageAll[i];
        position += 1;
    }

    // database name
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.DataBaseName.c_str()) + 1; i++) {
        data[position] = MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.DataBaseName[i];
        position += 1;
    }

    // plugin name: caching_sha2_password
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.ClientPluginName.c_str()) + 1; i++) {
        data[position] = MySQLClientSendInfo.MySQLClientSendInfoData.ClientPluginName[i];
        position += 1;
    }
    int len = send(fd, data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]), 0);



thank you for reply me.
all format in Protocol::HandshakeV10.i can not recv correct message.

well, have you tried comparing the official client's messages to yours? You may just be forgetting a packet. This is not a sufficiently [mre] that somebody can help you with. Also, you can simplify your code enormously if you split the generation of messages from the wire protocol encoding. And of course there is the question "why are you reimplementing libmysqlclient".
